# awebChromeHelper - what is it?

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, wordpress-gutenberg

```
<div id="awebChromeHelper"></div>
<div id="awebChromeHelper"></div>
```

I keep seeing this inserted to all my WYSIWYG gutenberg blocks and I have no clue what is causing it, has anyone seen this before?

Comment: I kept getting this issue too. It turned out to be one of my Chrome extensions. A web accessibility extension. I just removed it.